# AWS Lambda: 504 error when returning large data set

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, endpoint, aws-lambda

I have a Lambda function that takes several arrays (~6) and returns all possible combinations.

When there are a few hundred possible combinations, the Lambda is successful.  However, when there are several thousand possibilities, I get a failure (response below).

Note that I am compressing/decompressing the JSON in both directions to make the payload as small as possible.

I am running this with max memory (1536) and a 20 second timeout.

Any thoughts on what is causing this?

```
{
  "state": "rejected",
  "reason": {
    "name": "StatusCodeError",
    "statusCode": 504,
    "message": "504 - [object Object]",
    "error": {
      "message": "Endpoint request timed out"
    },
    "options": {
      "uri": "https://blahblah/prod/getCombinations",
      "method": "POST",
      "timeout": 120000,
      "json": {...
      },
      "simple": true,
      "resolveWithFullResponse": false
    },
    "response": {
      "statusCode": 504,
      "body": {
        "message": "Endpoint request timed out"
      },
      "headers": {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "content-length": "41",
        "connection": "close",
        "date": "Thu, 20 Aug 2015 20:39:53 GMT",
        "x-amzn-requestid": "965d3b8d-477b-11e5-99d6-4102846d4b1e",
        "x-cache": "Error from cloudfront",
        "via": "1.1 b1103856e287e98f322630821d3c6e5b.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)",
        "x-amz-cf-id": "Dhk7ylTq6RDE74smC8uF8ajms8rpU0fp2dnexn4_I3qIXgvrrsg48w=="
      },
      "request": {
        "uri": {
          "protocol": "https:",
          "slashes": true,
          "auth": null,
          "host": "blahblah",
          "port": 443,
          "hostname": "blahblah",
          "hash": null,
          "search": null,
          "query": null,
          "pathname": "/prod/getCombinations",
          "path": "/prod/getCombinations",
          "href": "https://blahblah"
        },
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
          "accept": "application/json",
          "content-type": "application/json",
          "content-length": 10201
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have just replaced the initial CloudFront forum reference in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32130237/45773) with a more specific documentation reference regarding the CloudFront 504 behavior.

Comment: At the risk of asking the obvious, what happens when you make the request directly to API Gateway (which I assume is how the lambda function is getting launched) instead of through CloudFront?  This doesn't look precisely like what I would expect to see if you were hitting the Cloudfront built-in 30 second request timeout timer, but rather that your function simply can't get the work done in the 20 second timeout you've provisioned, and API Gateway is returning the 504, which Cloudfront correctly returns to you... but you need to remove Cloudfront from the equation and verify that.

Comment: You're right - when I send the same test data using the Lambda console, the procedure succeeds.  However, sending a post from Fiddler (or my node app) results in the above behavior.

Answer (score 6):

You can read the [Amazon CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) 504 response "Endpoint request timed out" literally, i.e. a [504 Gateway Timeout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) generally indicates that *The server was acting as a gateway or proxy and did not receive a timely response from the upstream server.*

CloudFront complies to this standard, as explicated in [Customizing Error Responses](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/custom-error-pages.html) for example:

> **Server errors** indicate a problem with the origin server. For example, the HTTP server is busy or unavailable. When a server error occurs, either your origin server returns an HTTP status code in the 500 range to CloudFront, or **CloudFront doesn't get a response from your origin server for a certain period of time and assumes a 504 status code** (gateway timeout). *[emphasis mine]*

As Michael thankfully [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1695906/michael-sqlbot), CloudFront's own [request timeout for custom origins](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html#request-custom-request-timeout) is 30 seconds:

> DELETE, OPTIONS, PATCH, POST, and POST requests – If the origin doesn't respond within 30 seconds, CloudFront drops the connection and doesn't try again to contact the origin. The client can resubmit the request if necessary.

Given your [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) function has a shorter timeout of 20 seconds, I'd suspect your dataset to be too large already to be transmitted and processed via a POST request (presumably through [Amazon API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/)?!) within 20 seconds.

- If your dataset is larger than a 1.5GB Lambda function with a 20 seconds execution duration can handle, you would need to either slice your data into smaller chunks or migrate your computation off Lambda onto something more scalable - by chance the AWS Compute Blog just features a nice sample how to facilitate [Amazon ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/)
  for longer running tasks like this, see Chris Barclay's [Better Together: Amazon ECS
  and AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/better-together-amazon-ecs-and-aws-lambda/).

Comment: I don't think this error is being originated by Cloudfront.  It looks to me like the origin server is generating the error and Cloudfront is just returning what it receives.  `x-cache: error from cloudfront` doesn't necessarily mean Cloudfront threw the error, and a Cloudfront-originated 504 should have a `Content-Type: text/html` regardless of the request. FWIW,  Cloudfront's 504 timer is hard-coded to 30 seconds, and Cloudfront returned twice with the origin when that timer fires.

Comment: Ah, wasn't aware about CloudFront's hard-coded 30 seconds [request timeout for custom origins](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html#request-custom-request-timeout), thanks for this information (note that the two additional attempts only apply to `GET`/`HEAD` and not the `POST` at hand though) - accordingly, I've removed my ill advised recommendation to extend the Lambda execution timeout. Not sure about your `Content-Type` change assessment yet, it isn't explicated there - do you happen to have a reference for this?